# How to set Google Charts scales/intervals?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

How can I set the intervals on Google Charts?
I don't know if that's how it's called, but, in the image, they are the 200k, 400k and so on.
Since some of my values are pretty small, I need to create intervals at each 5k or so.

How can I set this using Google Charts?

The code I'm using is down here:
[image]

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart4);
    function drawChart4() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          <?php echo $dados; ?>
          ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {title: <?php echo "'".str_replace('_', ' ', $subtitulo)."'" ?>,
      },bars: 'horizontal',
      width: 1250,
      height: 350,
      colors: ['#4c4c4c','#07bb27']
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('column_horizontal'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Comment: those are considered `ticks`, however, they are not supported by _material_ charts. (`google.charts.Bar`) see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)